# To delete the counter line numbers and time-lines in a file

Tags: command-line, files, text-formatting

I have a file which is a subtitle (sub.srt or a text file) of a movie. But I wonder if there is a short way to delete all line-numbers and time-lines of the file. For example

```
85
00:07:39,250 --> 00:07:41,469
We got to be smart.
We're a ways from being finished.

86
00:07:41,628 --> 00:07:43,380
Shit, I can do this all week.

87
00:07:43,546 --> 00:07:44,547
We're gonna.

88
00:07:44,714 --> 00:07:49,352
We're like the Comanches,
little brother, raiding wherever we please
```

It must be turned out as

```
We got to be smart.
We're a ways from being finished.

Shit, I can do this all week.

 We're gonna.

We're like the Comanches,
little brother, raiding wherever we please
```

How can I reach this goal?

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`'s paragraph mode (`RS=`) causes each block of lines to be treated as an input record. Additionally, the field separator can be set to `\n` and fields from 3 onward printed - this assumes that line-number and time-line will always feature in the first two records within each block of records

```
awk -F '\n' -v RS= '{for (i=3; i<=NF; ++i) print $i; print ""}' file

We got to be smart.
We're a ways from being finished.

Shit, I can do this all week.

We're gonna.

We're like the Comanches,
little brother, raiding wherever we please
```

Comment: Besides so much thanks, I run the above command and it worked correctly. But when my file contains more lines for example 11 or larger it does not work. How can I modify the above command?

Comment: @Irreversible, the number of lines should not matter. Is there something about your file that you're not telling us?

Comment: Sorry my delay to response. I was wrestling with the problem. Please see https://ufile.io/wx014, the whole file is here. But I have tested just 11 line of that which did not work!!!!

Comment: https://gofile.io/?c=D5G4zs  it is better for downloading the original file

Comment: @Irreversible, works for me buddy. This is a long shot - try after replacing `awk` in the command line above with `gawk`

Comment: So sorry for my request, I was wondering if you send me (upload for me) a text file that you had obtained from the desired output. Thanks in advance. So sorry my request. But I have been busy to this work 1 past week without any output desired.